# Unusual CPU fan behaviour

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

I've recently installed a copy of Windows 7 on my new disk. The PC is geared towards quiet running, (half-passive PSU cooling, SSD disk) and I was very happy with the noise levels - the CPU fan was working very quietly when not in use by a game or some such.
This is an AMD Phenom II X2 555 3.2GHz on a GA-770T-USB3 MB.

The fan would work at full speed while the PC was booting up and then slow down once Windows finished initializing.

Today I've discovered, that there's something wrong going on - the fan is working at full speed no matter what (~2100RPM). The temperature remains very low (27 C). There is a service host process that's taking up 50% of the CPU power and over 1.5GB RAM (and growing!)- here's the list of services it's running https://i.stack.imgur.com/38F3D.jpg

What's changed since two days ago, when the CPU was quiet is that I've installed speedfan yesterday evening. However, uninstalling it doesn't really help.

Do you think there's something I can do to get the CPU fan to work quietly when not in use? Is there something suspicious about the service host I've shown? Is there any more information I should provide?

EDIT: BTW, Cool'n'Quiet (AMD's method of CPU fan speed control) is set to Auto in BIOS.

Comment: The AMD Phenom II X2 is a dual-core, and it sounds like your mystery process is using 100% of a single core, thereby raising the cpu temp and causing the fan to run faster. That's not unusual for the fan to speed up when the CPU warms up. That process is possibly stuck in some RAM eating loop, if you kill that process it should slow and cool everything down, though I don't know what it is or what it does, you'd need to check a more detailed process listing to find out, like in the Task  Manager or a windows equivalent of ps or top

Comment: Xen, you can see what the process does on the image I've linked.
I've tried killing the process but it gets back up.
Even so, I don't think the fan should be going at full speed when the CPU temp is only 26 C!

Comment: Services will usually auto-start if they are forced closed.  Going with what @Xen2050 is saying.  You need to look at Task manager and the processes tab to see what's using the CPU.  [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is good utility to see a little more depth on what's running what.

Comment: Guys, once again, I AM using process explorer and I've provided a screenshot from it, detailing what specific services are being run by the hungry process!

It appears speedfan was erroneously reporting temperatures, the CPU is actually at 37C right now. I've downlaoded Easytune (from Gigabyte) which allows me for manual fan speed control based on the temperature. I've also restarted the process in Process Explorer and it looks ok right now, we'll see how it goes.

Comment: ...and it's back to its old shenanigans. So, how should I identify which of the services in this process is causing the bloat? Just turn them off one by one?

Comment: double-click the svchost process and look at the Threads tab. It will tell you which service is using the CPU within.

Comment: Thanks Bigbio! And the culprit issss... Windows Update?! Well, that certainly explains a lot (the fresh install is doing lots of updates) but why would it need that much CPU just for downloading? This makes me think I need to disable automatic update downloading and only do it when I'm not working on the PC - the sluggishness and noise are really noticable.